# How is it that a Stored Procedure Parameter is not presented to the user in the SSRS Preview tab?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, reporting-services

A legacy Stored Procedure declares these parameters:

```
ALTER Procedure [dbo].[sp_ViewPriceMatrix_Variance_test2]
    @Unit varchar(4000),
    @BegDate datetime,
    @EndDate datetime,
    @SortBy varchar(20)
```

When I run the SSRS report, it doesn't show the "SortBy" parameter on the Preview pane, and the report runs fine (no errors, returns data).

How is the SortBy parameter hidden from the user? The only other places "SortBy" appears in the SP are three times where "IF(@SortBy='Members')" appears.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check report parameters under "Report Data" and check this parameter if marked as hidden with default value.

If not, please try deleting this dataset and adding again.

Answer (score 1):

In Reportbuilder:
 - Rightclick on the dataset >> "DataSet Properties" and click  "Refresh Fields"    and "ok"
The parameter should appear in Parameters.